# Kendo UI + Angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm starting a new project with kendo ui and I was wondering if anyone has any experience
integrating it with angular?
is there any prefered JS framework(e.g. backbone,knockout) for working with kendo ui?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-12-20/knockout_js_and_kendo_ui_-_a_potent_duo.aspx

Comment: now an official release: http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-06-24/announcing-angular-kendo-ui.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [kendo labs](http://labs.kendoui.com/#projects), they have integration examples for Angular, Backbone, Knockout ect.  Most are a work in progress, but hopefully it will get you started.  Just from the fact that Kendo is providing these integration examples there really is no one particular framework that works better, its your choice.  Hopefully as the Kendo labs projects progress we will see more end to end projects demonstrating integration with these frameworks as well as best practices.